# NSURLConnection is caching and reacting after a while

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I suspect it has to do with this new iOS9 `NSAppTransportSecurity` .

Well what happens is that i am sending a get request from iPhone which is received on the other side . Then when the other side send back data packs , i will only get the delegate starting to react after a while.

Seems there is some kind of cache that when its full, i only start getting  responds :

```
//sending
NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:data] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:100.0];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];
      NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:NO  ];
        [conn scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]
                              forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [conn start];
```

Where the receiving delegate goes like this :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"respond");

    _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}


    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
    {

        NSString *got=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"got:%@",got);  //**this logs only once, but all data appears at once.
```

When i log the respond i only see the word "got:" from the log -**once** . but the data packs ,which is multiple responds, is coming  all together :

```
//log
respond
got: respond1
respond2
respond3
respond4
got: respond5
got: respond6
got: respond7
```

Where the `responds` continue coming, but the delegate function it self is not being called.

Seems that he shows me all the FIRST packets in the cache **at once** !

**EDIT :**

Something very strange, when i see the respond i see it not in its http strucute:

```
got:HTTP/1.1 RESPOND  1
 Content-Type:application/json

HTTP/1.1 RESPOND  2
 Content-Type:application/json

HTTP/1.1 RESPOND  3
 Content-Type:application/json

HTTP/1.1 RESPOND  4
 Content-Type:application/json
```

Sent with :

```
respond="HTTP/1.1 RESPOND  \r\n Content-Type:application/json\r\n\r\n"
```

**EDIT 2**

Wow ! seems that only if my respond is long enough i get it right away when its being sent !

**The longer the respond the quicker i get it !**